# suggestions to upgrade my DSLR

Tags: canon, dslr, canon-7d, full-frame, nikon-d600

Before I ask this question itself I should be apologizing because this is an old question and is there in most of the forums and pages already,but some expert personal suggestions would be very helpful in here

I have been using my first DSLR EOS 1000D ever since January 1 2011 and has the kit 18-55mm lens and a sigma 70-300.
I feel like its high time to upgrade from that.
I had been looking into a bunch of options which include 7D,70D,5Dmark-2(not mark-3),
nikon D600

I'm super confused whether I should go for a full frame or an APS-C.

If I get a 7D(APS-C) I guess I could use my lenses(18-55 and sigma 70-300) same goes for the 70D as well. I don't know which I should go for, as 7D has been relatively old released way back in 2009 but a steady performer ever since or the relatively new 70D which pretty much matches with 7D.
I need to clarify whether I could use my lenses if I go full frame like 5D mark2.
and is the 5D mark2 way better than other options i have mentioned above

Or should i go for a complete switch from Canon and move to Nikon D600 which is a cheaper full frame camera and well rated

What are the suggestion for going for a preowned DSLR?
What should I look into before getting a preowned DSLR(if I should )?

I love clicking and i'm not too much into video 
Looking forward to some expert advices and suggestions

My budget ranges from $1000 to $1500

Comment: Missing from the question is the most important item: what's your budget ? Then anyway it seems to me that this kind of questions is better targeted at forums than at stackexchange.

Comment: the budget ranges from $1000 to $1500

Comment: The budget answers your full-frame question. If you buy a full-frame camera, you'll have nothing left for lenses.

Comment: 5DMkII if you can afford it. Best Canon APSC if you cannot. 
Why? -> Book a fireside and an everning to chat ... :-)

Comment: Russell 
I had been thinking over nikon D600
If going for the best canon APSC  which one do u think is better
7D or 70D
That was a portion of my whole big question

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions 
I moved to full frame 
Bought nikon d600 today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many questions all wrapped together, which individually already are answered.

- **Used or new:** [How risky is to buy a used camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21263/how-risky-is-to-buy-a-used-camera) and [Are refurbished digital SLR cameras okay to buy (and worth the small savings)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/are-refurbished-digital-slr-cameras-okay-to-buy-and-worth-the-small-savings)
- **Full Frame:** [When do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter-and-why)
- **Canon vs. Nikon:** [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)
- **Spending on body vs. lenses** [Is it lenses which make your photographs, not camera bodies?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18394/is-it-lenses-which-make-your-photographs-not-camera-bodies)
- **Can you use your existing lenses on a full-frame Canon?** [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)

---

I'm recommending the question be closed because the above information should help you, and because in general camera shopping questions are off-topic for a number of reasons. These pointers are because we also do like to be helpful around here. I've marked this answer as "community wiki" because it just points to existing content rather than providing anything new; anyone should feel free to add more links to existing questions where appropriate.

Comment: @MathewMGeorge You can also drop into [chat], where there are often people interested in discussing this kind of thing in a more informal way.